# beautifulsoup find function returning none

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap some information using beautifulsoup.
However, height keeps returning None. Could you please see what might be the problem?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/Affenpinscher/'
r = requests.get(url, headers= header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
height = soup.find('div', class_ = "f-16 my0 lh-solid breed-page__hero__overview__subtitle")
print(height)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMnGw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Content is provided dynamically - Always take a look into your soup and check if data you like to find is present. Result could differ slightly to wide from inspected result via developer tools, cause `requests` do not render the website and makr adjustments like a browser would do.

So your `soup.find('div', class_ = "f-16 my0 lh-solid breed-page__hero__overview__subtitle")` won't find anything and results in `None`

#### How to fix?

Information is stored in a script tag - You can use `BeautifulSoup` to find the tag and `json.loads()` to access the values.

#### Example

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.80 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/Affenpinscher/'
r = requests.get(url, headers= header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

json.loads(soup.select('[type="application/ld+json"]')[2].text)
```

#### Output

```
{'@context': ['http://schema.org', {'csvw': 'http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw#'}], '@type': 'Dataset', 'name': 'Affenpinscher', 'description': 'The Affenpinscher: loyal, curious, and famously amusing; this almost-human toy dog is fearless out of all proportion to his size. As with all great comedians, it’s the Affenpinscher’s apparent seriousness of purpose that makes his antics all the more amusing.', 'url': 'https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/affenpinscher/', 'sameAs': 'https://images.akc.org/pdf/breeds/standards/Affenpinscher.pdf', 'mainEntity': {'@type': 'csvw:Table', 'csvw:tableSchema': {'csvw:columns': [{'csvw:name': 'Height', 'csvw:datatype': 'string', 'csvw:cells': [{'csvw:value': 'Height: 9-11.5 inches'}]}, {'csvw:name': 'Weight', 'csvw:datatype': 'string', 'csvw:cells': [{'csvw:value': 'Weight: 7-10 pounds'}]}, {'csvw:name': 'Life Expectancy', 'csvw:datatype': 'string', 'csvw:cells': [{'csvw:value': 'Life Expectancy: 12-15 years'}]}, {'csvw:name': 'Group', 'csvw:datatype': 'string', 'csvw:cells': [{'csvw:value': 'Group: Toy Group'}]}]}}}
```

---

Access the table values like this:

```
table = json.loads(soup.select('[type="application/ld+json"]')[2].text)['mainEntity']['csvw:tableSchema']['csvw:columns']

for r in table:
    print(r['csvw:cells'][0]['csvw:value'])

#output
Height: 9-11.5 inches
Weight: 7-10 pounds
Life Expectancy: 12-15 years
Group: Toy Group
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this will help me to extract, height, weight and lif However, I am still wondering why height = soup.find('div', class_ = "f-16 my0 lh-solid breed-page__hero__overview__subtitle") this would not work. I want

Comment: Happy to help and updated answer, to make a bit more clear, why you get `None` as result.

Comment: Wow, I learned something today! I always thought that soup is exactly the same as what I see in the insepect. 1) So in this particular soup, does it not contain all the "script" that I see on the inspect?  2) How do you normally check whether they(insepct and soup) are different? 3) If they are different and soup does not contain information about let's say "All Traits" tab or "About the Breed" section, how do i scrap?

Comment: There are a lot of strategies - First check your soup, look for an api (offical or network tab), use selenium, ... So go for it and if you get stuck with your code, this will be predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) .